# Get values from subobject in Razor HTML

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I have a class that contains a super object. When creating this class, it will contain one of the subobjects of the superobject. However, because the attributes of the subobjects are not in the superobject, I cannot access these attributes in Razor. Can someone tell me how I can reach the subobjects' attributes? I cannot put the subobjects' attributes in the superobject, because I'm going to convert the class to json and I cannot have all attributes visible in the json.

Class:

```
public class FoundPattern
{
    public Pattern Pattern = new Pattern();
}
```

Superobject:

```
public class Pattern : OntologicalModel
{       
}
```

Subobjects:

```
public class KpiPattern : Pattern
{
    public List<KPI> KPIs = new List<KPI>();
}
```

.

```
public class ProcessPattern : Pattern
{
    public List<Process> Processes = new List<Process>();
}
```

Razor page:

```
@model IEnumerable<FoundPattern>
@foreach (var x in item.SUBOBJECTNAME.SUBOBJECTATTRIBUTE)
{
    // do something     
}
```

Instead of `SUBOBJECTNAME` and `SUBOBJECTATTRIBUTE` I need the subobject and subobject attribute, respectively.

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: @EhsanSajjad In the Razor page, I cannot get the object I want. I want to get `item.KpiPattern.KPIs`. Instead I can only choose `item.Pattern`.

Comment: If you check the type of the item and the do a cast to that object: `if(item is ProcessPattern) { (ProcessPattern)item.SUBOBJECTATTRIBUTE }`

Comment: @torsan I cannot choose the subobject attributes. I can only do this: `(ProcessPattern)item.Pattern`.

Comment: @torsan the code was wrong. I fixed it, but it is still not letting me choose the attributes: `if(item.Pattern is ProcessPattern) { (ProcessPattern)item.Pattern.Processes}`

Comment: @torsan I think I partially solved the problem: `@if (item.Pattern is KpiPattern){ KpiPattern pt = (KpiPattern)item.Pattern; }`. Next, I will use `pt` to do the rest. However the if-statement is not correct. It's never true.

Comment: @torsan Nevermind. It doesn't work without if-statement, either. I get the following error: `Unable to cast object of type 'KPItool.Models.Pattern' to type 'KPItool.Models.KpiPattern'`

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like

```
@foreach (var x in Model)
{
    if(x.Pattern is ProcessPattern) { 
        foreach (var y in ((KpiPattern)x.Pattern).Processes)
        { 
            //enter code here
        }
    }
    if(x.Pattern is KpiPattern) { 
        foreach (var y in ((KpiPattern)x.Pattern).KPIs)
        { 
            //enter code here
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't have intellisense or the view is showing syntax errors then a possible issue is that you didn't include the namespace of your classes in your `web.config` in your `Views` folder.

Remember to open and close the view after editing the `web.config` for the intellisense to start working correctly.

Comment: I cannot find web.config in my Views folder or somewhere else in the solution.

Comment: No web.config in solution? Is it a .NET Core solution?

Comment: @Nirman Yes. Apparently, that's normal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542328/web-config-missing-when-creating-asp-net-core-web-app-in-vs-2017-rc Maybe I need to edit appsettings.json, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: oh ok! yes, there is no web.config in .NET core.. please update your question, and/or add a tag in the post so it gets noticed to the .net core skills specialists.

Comment: @Zarif If thts the case then you can still fully qualify the classes in the view like `@model IEnumerable<MyNameSpace.Models.FoundPattern>`

Comment: @LiefdeWen I changed it to `@model IEnumerable<KPItool.Models.FoundPattern>`, but I still get an error: `'Pattern' does not contain a definition for 'KPIs' and no extension method 'KPIs' accepting a first argument of type 'Pattern' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Are you passing a `KpiPattern` to the view, if you are then just do as I edited my answer

Comment: @LiefdeWen Sorry I don't understand. I'm passing a list of `FoundPattern` to the view. Every `FoundPattern` can contain a `KpiPattern` or a `ProcessPattern`.