# Am confused about web.config in .NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, web-config

There are a bunch of contradictory statements about web.config and .NET Core.

- Places saying it's gone.

  - https://dotnetcore.show/episode-10-configuration-in-net-core/
- Places saying it **was** gone but now it's back.

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46771737/1662268
- Places saying that it's no longer necessary, but you can create one manually:

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43890405/1662268
  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53731666/1662268

Additionally, I've just deployed a mostly-fresh-out-of-the-box .NET Core app to Azure.
In the repository, there's no web.config but when I explore the deployed code in Kudu, there IS a web.config file?

---

What's going on with web.config in .NET Core?
How are you supposed to do non-Custom-App-Configuration stuff? (e.g. HTTP headers and other HTTP level config)

Answer (score 22):

In a .NET Framework Web application, web.config is used for two purposes:

1. To store configuration for the web application.
2. To store configuration for the IIS that hosts the application (`system.webServer` element).

In a .NET Core Web application, you have at least two choices for storing application configuration:

- Use a [.NET Core Configuration Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2), often with a json configuration file.
- Use the [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/) NuGet package with recent versions of .NET Core (2.0+ I think).  One advantage of using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` is that it can be used in .NET Standard 2.0 libraries that are compatible with both .NET Core and .NET Framework.

If you choose to use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` in a .NET Core web application, you need to add an `app.config` (not `web.config`) file to your Visual Studio project.  When you build this project it will be copied to the output directory and renamed as `appName.dll.config`.

If you are hosting your .NET Core web application in IIS, you can still need a `web.config` file with configuration for IIS (`system.webServer` element).  I.e. your application may need both `app.Config` and `web.config`.

Personally I prefer to use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` and an `app.config` XML configuration file, for several reasons including compatibility with .NET Framework, the fact that it's easy to comment out bits of XML, etc.  YMMV of course.

Comment: you deserved my up vote for this sentence "you need to add an app.config (not web.config)"

Answer (score 2):

Read a few `web.config` examples from Google and you should notice that,

1. ASP.NET/WCF 2.x/4.x uses it to store configuration (tags like `<system.web>`).
2. IIS uses it to store configuration (tags like `<system.webServer>`).

So migrating to ASP.NET Core only make the first obsolete, and you should only say goodbye to that piece of knowledge.

If you host your web app on IIS, then `web.config` is still needed, as you need initial settings there to configure ASP.NET Core module for IIS/IIS Express (`dotnet publish` generates such a file if you don't have your own).

Comment: This answer is a bright light in a sea of misinfo. A web.config is truly still needed for hosting on IIS. You can also control URL rewriting and redirecting in a web.config outside the application if you choose to do so.