# ASP.NET Core 6 routing in Azure App Service with ".dd" ending in the url

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API that has a simple endpoint
`/resources/{id}` where `id` is a string. Everything worked as expected in local development. We then deployed it to a standard Azure App Service.

We got a bug report when this particular URL was requested `/resources/d.dd`. The response was

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I have tried with these variations

1. `resources/d.dd/`
2. `resources/d.vn` (and other top-level domain name)
3. `resources/hello.dd`
4. `resources/d.ddd`
5. `resources/d.txt`

All worked except for `d.dd` without the last `/` in the URL.

I ran it locally. It worked. The `d.dd` was parsed and seen as the id.

It seems that `.dd` is routed as a file extension by the webserver on Azure. I spent hours looking around and checking Azure settings. I found nothing.

I am looking for a hint or suggestion. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

We can [create a `web.config` manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53731666/7687666), and copy the content from azure and paste it.

Every time when you deploy it, it will include this web.config file.

**Like：**

[image]

**Test Result**

[image]

Comment: That requires a manual update directly in the web.config of the Azure App Service. The config is gone when the app is redeployed (from an ARM template). I wonder if there is any alternative or something in the App Service from Microsoft

Comment: @ThaiAnhDuc We can create `web.config` manually, you can find the details in the link I have updated it. And your issue can be fixed.